# Knockout.js mapping not updating

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin, knockout-mvc

I have a table of records. Whenever I get the data from the server I want to update a certain field in my ViewModel.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var data = JSON.parse($("#model").val());
    var vm = new koViewModel(data);
    ko.applyBindings(vm);

    ....
    //ajax call -> update viewModel
    {
         vm.loadData(data);
    }

});

var koViewModel = function (data) {
    var self = this;
    self.items = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
    };

    self.getRecord = function (id) {
        var match = ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.items(), function (item) {
            return item.Id() === id;
        });
        if (match) {
            return match;
        }
    };

    self.loadData = function (data) {
        $.each(data.ComponentBases, function (i, item) {
            ko.mapping.fromJS(item, {}, self.getRecord(item.Id));
        })
    };
};
```

HTML:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: items">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: Name"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: VerifyResult.Message"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Whenever I call loadData() function with less than 3 records it updates fine. However when I have 3 or more at least one of them will not update properly even though there was a match on the Id field.

What could be the reason?

Comment: Do the types of the Id field always match? Maybe somewhere the Id is a number, and you're checking it with a string. To see if this is the problem, change `item.Id() === id` to `item.Id() == id`.

Comment: tried it. still fails for some records. I did a console.log on the match and it does match all the records but doesn't update all of them as it should at times.

Comment: Are you able te reproduce this with jsfiddle?